# Kinetic breaks when dragging one image (panning) on top of another

Tags: kineticjs

So I tried to simplify my code as much as possible, basically creating two stages, two draggable layers, each with an image. (I tried to create a JSfiddle but it seems that draggable doesn't work at all there)

```
<html>

<body>
  <div id="view1" style="float:left;"></div>
  <div style="float:left;">--</div>
  <div id="view2" style="float:left;"></div>
</body>

<script type='text/javascript' src="http://d3lp1msu2r81bx.cloudfront.net/kjs/js/lib/kinetic-v4.3.3.min.js"></script>

<script>

for (var i = 0; i < 2; i++) {
    var divName = 'view' + (i + 1);

    var stage = new Kinetic.Stage({
        container: divName,
        width: 200,
        height: 200
    });

    var kineticLayer = new Kinetic.Layer();
    kineticLayer.setDraggable("draggable");
    stage.add(kineticLayer);

    var image = new Image();
    image.onload = imageOnLoad;
    image.kineticLayer=kineticLayer;

    image.src = 'http://2.bp.blogspot.com/-lwBsEScRW_U/T-Hwz0-CVGI/AAAAAAAAKjY/2RC9pFcXRsE/s1600/Muppets.JPG';
}


function imageOnLoad() {
    this.kineticLayer.removeChildren();

    var kineticImage = new Kinetic.Image({
        image: this
    });

    this.kineticLayer.add(kineticImage);
    this.kineticLayer.draw();
}

</script>

</html>
```

When you press and hold on the image and move it around it pans ok, but when the you move the cursor (while pressing and holding) on top of the other image, kinetic breaks with the error "Uncaught TypeError:Cannot read property 'x' of undefined"

EDIT: jsfiddle jsfiddle.net/LFeDg/ thx to EliteOctagon

EDIT: this 'bug' ONLY happens with chrome developer tools opened !

I need the panning action to keep working as long as the cursor is held no matter where it's going (I don't need drag and drop in this case at all), how can I fix this ? is this a kinetic bug ?

Thank you!

Comment: Looks like bug. I think kineticjs doesn't work well outside of stage.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a jsfiddle of the code you posted: http://jsfiddle.net/LFeDg/

You do not have what you are describing at the beginning. You have two stages, each with a layer and image in it.

Try writing your code without the loop structure and using a different version of kineticjs. Like:

```
stage1 = new Kinetic.Stage();
stage2 = new Kinetic.Stage();
```

etc.

Comment: Hi thanks for answering and the JSfiddle !

Ok interesting, using your fiddle I realized the problem only happens when you have the chrome developer tools open, then it will break as I wrote in my msg though you can resume it. Why would that happen ? again is this a kinetic bug or am I doing something wrong ?

Comment: Also you're right, I have two stages not one. Can you please comment if that is the right way to implement what I want (A few images displayed each with the ability to be panned inside it's layer) ?

Thanks!